# Observable gets triggered twice

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, observable

In an Angular app, I implemented Infinite scroll with intersection observer. When the scroll reaches the end of the page, the `loadNext()` method gets invoked in order to fetch the following batch of results.

However the for some reason, the code within the subscribe method is executed twice, with the result the hat the same results are returned twice. If I use `take(1)` operator, everything works as expected, but it's a workaround I would like to avoid.

The **component**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'monorepo-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public places: Place[] = [];
  public places$: Observable<Place[]> | undefined;
  public canShare = false;

  private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor(
    private placesService: PlacesService,
    private router: Router,
    private shareApi: ShareApiService,
    private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canShare = this.shareApi.canShare();
    this.placesService
      .getFirstSet()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((data: Place[]) => {
        this.places = data;
          this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
  }

  loadNext() {
    this.placesService
    .getNextSet()
    .pipe(
        // If scrollY is 0, means that it is the first call of IntersectionObserver
        filter(_ => window.scrollY > 0),
        takeUntil(this.destroy$)
        )
      .subscribe((nextPageData: Place[]) => {

        // ----- Here nextPageData returns twice  -----
        this.places.push(...nextPageData);
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
  }
```

The **component template**:

```
<monorepo-infinite-scroll (scrolledDown)="loadNext()">
<section>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let place of places; trackBy: trackByPlaceId">
      <div class="list-card pointer">

...
```

The **infiniteScroll component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'monorepo-infinite-scroll',
  template: `
    <div #header></div>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div #footer></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./infinite-scroll.component.scss'],
})
export class InfiniteScrollComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

...

ngOnInit() {
    const options = {
      root: this.root,
      rootMargin: this.rootMargin,
      threshold: this.threshold,
    };

    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        this.scrolledDown.emit();
      }
    }, options);

    this.observer.observe(this.footer.nativeElement);
  }
```

The **service** method:

```
getNextSet(): Observable<Place[]> {
    return this.db.nextDataPage<Place>(this.PLACE_COLLECTION, this.lastDocInPage)
    .pipe(
      map((places) => {
        this.lastDocInPage = this.getLastDoc(places);
        return places;
      })
    );
  }
```

The **Data Layer** service:

```
nextDataPage<T>(collectionName: string, lastDoc: T, orderBy): Observable<T[]> {
    const query = (ref: CollectionReference) =>
      ref
        .orderBy(orderBy.propName, orderBy.order)
         .startAfter((lastDoc as any)[orderBy.propName])
        .limit(9);

    // Using .pipe(take(1)), returns only one result.
    return this.firestore.collection<T>(collectionName, query)
               .valueChanges()
               .pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }
```

Comment: can you share your html and how are using the loadNext() method?

Comment: Added the template part and the infiniteScroll component. It triggers the DB call once the scroll reaches the page bottom.